# Image Slider: Working with the widths

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <body>

<div id="parent_scroll">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="slides">Slide1</div>
        <div class="slides">Slide2</div>
        <div class="slides">Slide3</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>



<style>
    #parent_scroll{
        width: 800px;
        height: 350px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
#slider{
    width: 2430px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
}

.slides{
    width: 800px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    float: left;
    background-color: grey;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I am trying to implement a slide show sort of a feature. But i am not sure what logic goes into the javascript over here, i know i need to use a setInterval() function. The only part is how i would work out the width of the element with the id:"slider". Pointers would be helpful
EDIT: **trying to implement this without jQuery**

Comment: @webkit sorry i am trying implement this one without jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your CSS that your widths are static, but if you were to add slides you should
calculate the #slider width using the width of .slides times the amount of slides..

Then, save your .slides width (including margin) as your offset, and animate #slider's left position using the offset..

**EDIT**: Actually, there's another technique I've been fiddling with so you won't have to calculate the widths, and that's using display inline-block like this:

```
#slider { white-space:nowrap;}
.slides { display:inline-block;}
```

this will automatically have all your slides on the same line and then you can animate using margins.

Let me know if that clears it up for you.. do you need a code example?

**EDIT:** example (using css animations)

### Javascript

```
var slider, slides, offset, amount, _timer, _curindex = 0;
        
function initSlider() {
    slider = document.getElementById("slider");
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    
    offset = slides[0].offsetWidth+2;
    amount = slides.length;
  
    slider.style.width = offset*amount;

    _timer = setInterval(moveSlide, 3000);
}

function moveSlide() {
    _curindex = (_curindex == amount-1) ? 0 : _curindex+1;   
    slider.style.left = -_curindex*offset+"px";
}
initSlider();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/733nt/)

Comment: @user3750842 added an example and fiddle above

Comment: yeah this works, when i was working it out i was stuck on offsetWidth, but i see how it works thnxs

Answer (score 0):

you should try this code

```
<div id="div1" class="slides" style="width:800px...">Slide1</div>`
```

and in js code

```
var slide1 = document.getElementById("div1");
//if you want to add width
slide1.style.width= parseInt(slide1.style.width) + 100 + "px";`
```

Comment: add onClick event on div and put this on that event.. function imgclick(){ slide1.style.width = "200px"}

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Pure HTML CSS:

```
<div id="parent_scroll">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="slides"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div class="slides"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/00ff00/000000" alt=""></div>
        <div class="slides"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/0000ff/000000" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>

DIV#parent_scroll{
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

DIV#slider{
    position: relative;
    width: 1050px;
    animation: slideme 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: slideme 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes slideme {
    0%   {left: 0;}
    33%  {left: -350px;}
    67%  {left: -700px;}
    100% {left: 0;}
} 
@-webkit-keyframes slideme {
    0%   {left: 0;}
    33%  {left: -350px;}
    67%  {left: -700px;}
    100% {left: 0;}
} 

DIV.slides{
    float: left;
}

DIV#slider:before, DIV#slider:after{
    display: table;
    content: "";
}
DIV#slider:after{
    clear: both;
}
DIV#slider{
    zoom: 1
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yLTKe/3/

Add JS to make it dynamic

Comment: Nice, but as you mention in your answer, it's a very static and limited option.. where sliders are usually dynamic in width and amount of slides

Comment: @webkit: I know but it should give him a hint on how to implement a static Slider with pure CSS. It's not clear to me what the TO exactly needs to know.